# How to remove dataloading.net?

Tags: safari, virus

On my father's mac, dataloading.net keeps popping up in tabs. It doesn't seem to be in Safari's extensions (at least not visible in preferences). He has clean my mac 3 installed. Can this problem be solved with that?

I'm having trouble recommending any virus scanner, because there's a lot of crapware out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect your Mac may have malware or adware installed on it, I would recommend trying BitDefender, a lightweight antivirus app for Mac (available [for free on the Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bitdefender-virus-scanner/id500154009?mt=12)), which I have found to be especially good at detecting both adware and malware and then removing it. BitDefender scans your machine when prompted (good for an ongoing issue) but does nothing in the background.

If you want constant protection in the future (that promises to block this kind of adware/malware from being downloaded onto your Mac in the first place, and has fulfilled its promise twice for me) you can try [Avast](https://www.avast.com/en-us/mac), which is also free (but not available from the Mac App Store, just their website).

Hope this helps, let me know if this fixes the problem or not!

Comment: I would recommend the free [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/) as well as BitDefender. Malwarebytes does a scan for malware and adware.

Comment: My father removed the page from the Safari history, and now it isn't happening anymore. I've sent him the link to this answer, and he'll try out bitdefender when this comes back. I've never heard of removing from history to solve a problem like this. Could Safari's 'top sites' thingy be prerendering the site and executing javascript?

Comment: @bigblind Seriously don't think that the top sites feature would run any Javascript, that would cause all sorts of problems. Could be that that site exploits some vulnerability, but I kind of doubt that. Not sure how deleting it from history would fix anything, given that the issue seems to be caused by some malware (just google 'dataloading.net virus mac'). Most likely it'll start back up again until you get rid of whatever code is running it (I see that Malwarebytes has fixed this issue for others, though I don't like it as much in general I recommend it too for this specific scenario).

Comment: Bitdefender says there was no malware found, but dataloading.net still shows up.

Comment: @bigblind Uh-oh! Try [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/) since it's confirmed by others to solve this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Running Malwarebytes in "normal" mode didn't work for me, but it did when run it when in "Safe mode":

1. Shut down your Mac. Press the power button and after you hear the startup sound press and hold the shift button. Release it when the logo appears.

   It will start in safe mode. The screen will flicker and it takes a lot to start.

   Log in and open Safari. Copy and paste this url:

   https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/mac/

   Download and open. Copy to applications and run. Select SCAN. It should detect your malware, Remove All.

   When if finishes, close MalwareBytes.
2. Disable Extensions and test.

   Safari > Preferences > Extensions
   Select and disable all extensions and test. 
   Uninstall all extensions you not installed knowingly.
   To uninstall any extension, select it and click the “Uninstall” button.
3. Safari > Preferences > Search > Search engine:
    Select your preferred search engine.
4. Visit the site you want it to be the Home page

   Safari > Preferences > General >  Homepage
   Click the button “Set to Current Page” button.
5. Restart the Mac.

> "I can't believe someone is creating malware for Mac"...

Answer (score -1):

I just finished removing dataloading-net/j/pne from Safari 10.0.2 ( Sierra and all security updates done) this way:
- Shutdown your Mac
- Reboot with shift key down (disables all extensions other than OSX )
- Launch MalwareBytes anti malware, scan and remove the threads.
- Reboot, and hope you're done (it worked for me !)